# Android как сделать GET запрос

Tags: android

Мне при нажатии на кнопку в MainActivity надо запросить данные
Есть специальный адрес по которому они лежать в json представлении

Мне кажется или в java все как то сложно?)

Права для интернета я указал.
Все, с кодом проблемы)

```
URL url = new URL("http://hashcode.ru").openStream()
```

Тут подчеркивает красным строчку с адресом.... (((

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
 public static String doGet(String url)
            throws Exception {

        URL obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();

        //add reuqest header
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0" );
        connection.setRequestProperty("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");   

        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
        String inputLine;
        StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

        while ((inputLine = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            response.append(inputLine);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();

//      print result
        Log.d(TAG,"Response string: " + response.toString());


        return response.toString();
    }
```

Использовать можно так:

```
    new AsyncTask<Void, String, String>() {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(Void... voids) {
            String s = "";
            try {
                s = doGet(myURL);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return s;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(final String result) {
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    tvRez.setText(result);
                }
            });
        }
    }.execute();
```

Comment: как использовать эту функцию doGet?
Делаю так - подсвечивает красным
tvRez.setText(doGet(myURL));

Comment: try {
                    tvRez.setText(doGet(myURL));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

Comment: Красное ушло, но при запуске студия у меня нафиг зависла. на телефоне приложение запустилось но чето не пашет. 
А студия так и висит...
Разве в андроиде запросы по правилам не надо делать в асинхронных задачах? Может изза этого

Comment: @АлексЛизенберг да, там что то  типа NetworkOnMainThread,  я добавил в ответ AsyncTask

Comment: Вот теперь пашет.
Но вопрос. Можно как то по лаконичнее использование не 15 строк
а одна 2 строки. и еще как передать внутрь этой AsyncTask переменную? мне пришлось внутри ее объявлять новую переменную с адресом. внешнюю он не берет

Comment: да, можно унаследовать класс AsyncTask создать там конструктор и передавать нужныее данные, и по-моему можно через вызов метода .execute() передавать параметры которые вы указываете AsyncTask<Void, String, String>() поищите в гугле, это можно сделать, по поводу лаконичности - можно, но это не значит что в целом кода станет меньше)

Comment: Да свернул его в новый класс и вроде норм пашет. Щас разберусь как передавать урл

Comment: А подскажи, это же все работает в отдельном потоке, как можно по завершению как будет получен ответ вызвать 
уже метод mainactivity raschet()

Comment: все разобрался) теперь надо с json что то решить 
можеть есть пример как со строкой работать, которая в json?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5566669/how-to-parse-a-json-object-in-android

Comment: Крутяг со всем разобрался, буду рассчитывать сейчас. Спасиб

Answer (score 1):

Делал с помощью потока:

```
public class JsonTask extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
{
    private final String URL = "google.com";
    private ArrayList<NameValuePair> postParams = new ArrayList<>();
    private JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute()
    {
        super.onPreExecute();
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params)
    {
            postParams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("ParamKey", "ParamValue"));
            jsonObject = JSONParser.makeHttpRequest(URL, "GET", postParams);
            return jsonObject.toString();
    }
}
```

и Вот сам парсер для разбора JSON:

```
public class JSONParser {
    static InputStream is = null;
    static JSONObject jObj = null;
    static String json = "";

        public static JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method, List<NameValuePair> params) {
            try {
                if (method == "POST") {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
                    httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();
                } else if (method == "GET") {
                    DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                    String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
                    url += "?" + paramString;
                    HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);
                    HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
                    HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
                    is = httpEntity.getContent();
                }
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Internet Error.")
            }
            try {
                BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                String line = null;
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    sb.append(line + "\n");
                }
                is.close();
                json = sb.toString();
            } catch (Exception e) {
                System.out.println("Buffer Error : Error converting result " + e.toString());
            }
            try {
                jObj = new JSONObject(json);
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println("JSON Parser: + Error parsing data " + e.toString());
            }
            return jObj;
        }
    }
```

Comment: А можно пример как все это использовать строчку?
Например запросить УРЛ и как обращаться потом к элементам

Comment: И у меня кстати везде подчеркивает static красным

Comment: Да есть пример тут [ссылка](https://github.com/goodvin1709/JSONsender)

Comment: Чет замудрено) как то, устал разбираться с этими красными ошибками